# Comparison of array elements and objects properties return false

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

I want to output which array elements are equal to objects properties.

Array and Object are like that:

```
var groupProperties = {
    "processors": ["producent: ","model-line: ","model: ","freq: ","cores: ","threads: ","quantity: ","netto_price: "],

    "graphics": ["producent: ","model_line: ","model: ","vram: ","directx: ","quantity: ","netto_price: "],

    "motherboards": ["producent: ","model_line: ","model: ","chipset: ","quantity: ","netto_price: "]
};

var groups = [
    PROCESSORS
    ,AMD|ATHLON|7750|2.6|6|2|7|250.00
    INTEL|i7|720QM|2.8|4|8|5|450.25
    INTEL|i5|4570|3.2|4|4|4|345.50
    ,GRAPHICS
    ,AMD|RADEON|7790|1GB|11|3|300.90
    NVIDIA|GEFORCE|8800GTS|512MB|10|1|150.99
    ,MOTHERBOARDS
    ,MSI|GAMING|GD-65|Z87|5|510.30
    ASUS|RAMPAGE|MAXIMUS-VII|Z87|6|890.99
    ASUS|UNKNOWN|P5KC|P35|1|50.00
];
```

My function, which doesn't work (**if statement** returns false, don't know why):

```
for (var index in groups) {
    for(var property in groupProperties) {
        console.log('PROPS '+property);
        console.log("second loop \n");
        console.log("ARRAY "+groups[index]);
        if(groups[index] === property.toUpperCase()) { 
             console.log("third loop \n");
             console.log("Array elements equal with object properties "+groups[index]);
        }
    }            
}
```

Output should be: **'PROCESSORS', 'GRAPHICS', 'MOTHERBOARDS'**.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**@edit**
I discovered that's something is wrong with **groups** array, cause in console it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbX2t.jpg

So i give whole code with manipulating on all origin array. I hope somebody helps with fixing it up.:

```
// var content <= there is text loaded from '.txt' file

            var splittedRows= content.split('\n');
            console.log("Splitted: \n"+ splittedRows);

            var groups = [];
            var inner = 0;

            for (index in splittedRows)
            {
                if (splittedRows[index].indexOf('GRP') == 0)
                {
                    groups[index] = splittedRows[index].slice('PRD|'.length);
                    inner = Number(index) + 1;
                        console.log('inner '+inner);
                    continue;
                }
                if (groups[inner] === undefined)
                {
                    groups[inner] = splittedRows[index].slice('PRD|'.length);
                    continue;
                }
                groups[inner] += splittedRows[index].slice('PRD|'.length);
            }
            console.log(groups);

            for(i=0; i<groups.length; i++)
            {

                if (!groups[i])
                {
                    groups.splice(i,1);
                    i--;
                }
                    //console.log("Moved "+groups[i]);
            }
```

Also source from where text is loaded up:

> GRP|PROCESSORS PRD|AMD|ATHLON|7750|2.6|6|2|7|250.00
>   PRD|INTEL|i7|720QM|2.8|4|8|5|450.25 PRD|INTEL|i5|4570|3.2|4|4|4|345.50
>   GRP|GRAPHICS PRD|AMD|RADEON|7790|1GB|11|3|300.90
>   PRD|NVIDIA|GEFORCE|8800GTS|512MB|10|1|150.99 GRP|MOTHERBOARDS
>   PRD|MSI|GAMING|GD-65|Z87|5|510.30
>   PRD|ASUS|RAMPAGE|MAXIMUS-VII|Z87|6|890.99
>   PRD|ASUS|UNKNOWN|P5KC|P35|1|50.00

**@edit2**

I fixed **groups** array by **splice'ing** `undefined` elements and **slice'ing** '\r' chars out from array elements. 
Now all works - i can compare array elements with properties of object.

Comment: Your groups are missing quotes.

Comment: Is that the code you're using??!?!? That's not JS.

Comment: @SimpleJ, groups elements are String type, i just pasted array output from console.

**Amit**, what do you mean? All works except of if in inner loop. If i set **!==**, then some elements are appearing, but not those which i want to

Comment: You shouldn't be using `for in` loops to iterate over arrays. Use a regular `for` loop, an iteration function (`forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, etc), or a `for of` loop if its supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily acomplish this using `Array.prototype.filter` and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`:

```js
var groupProperties = {
    "processors": ["producent: ","model-line: ","model: ","freq: ","cores: ","threads: ","quantity: ","netto_price: "],

    "graphics": ["producent: ","model_line: ","model: ","vram: ","directx: ","quantity: ","netto_price: "],

    "motherboards": ["producent: ","model_line: ","model: ","chipset: ","quantity: ","netto_price: "]
};

var groups = [
    "PROCESSORS",
    "AMD|ATHLON|7750|2.6|6|2|7|250.00",
    "INTEL|i7|720QM|2.8|4|8|5|450.25",
    "INTEL|i5|4570|3.2|4|4|4|345.50",
    "GRAPHICS",
    "AMD|RADEON|7790|1GB|11|3|300.90",
    "NVIDIA|GEFORCE|8800GTS|512MB|10|1|150.99",
    "MOTHERBOARDS",
    "MSI|GAMING|GD-65|Z87|5|510.30",
    "ASUS|RAMPAGE|MAXIMUS-VII|Z87|6|890.99",
    "ASUS|UNKNOWN|P5KC|P35|1|50.00"
];

var propGroups = groups.filter(function(group) {
    return groupProperties.hasOwnProperty(group.toLowerCase());
});

console.log(propGroups);
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. My **groups** array is kinda weird. Your proposal function **propGroups** returned empty object - it works when i copy/paste your whole snippet, but if I only use function, empty object shows up in console.
My **groups** array is created from other array, where there was used **split** method, and earlier origin content of this array was loaded from **.txt* file.** I checked and **groups** array is **String type**, so i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: If it's returning an empty array, none of the groups match keys in groupProperties. You may need to parse the groups further (trim, remove symbols, etc). I removed the leading commas from the groups which might relate to your issue.

Comment: Now i discovered that there is something wrong with **groups** array. This showed up in console [link](http://imgur.com/FH7Geu8)

Comment: That's whole code with manipulating origin array: [link](http://wklej.org/id/1834824/) and origin text was loaded from **.txt** file which is like that: [link](http://wklej.org/id/1834821/)

Comment: It looks as though you need to remove whitespace (\r) from the elements of the array and filter null values.

Comment: Shouldn't `null` or `undefined` values be removed after this line in my code`if (groups[inner] === undefined)                    groups[inner] = splittedRows[index].slice('PRD|'.length);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap those array entries in quotes, like this:

```
var groups = [
  "PROCESSORS",
  "AMD|ATHLON|7750|2.6|6|2|7|250.00",
  "INTEL|i7|720QM|2.8|4|8|5|450.25",
  "INTEL|i5|4570|3.2|4|4|4|345.50",
  "GRAPHICS",
  "AMD|RADEON|7790|1GB|11|3|300.90",
  "NVIDIA|GEFORCE|8800GTS|512MB|10|1|150.99",
  "MOTHERBOARDS",
  "MSI|GAMING|GD-65|Z87|5|510.30",
  "ASUS|RAMPAGE|MAXIMUS-VII|Z87|6|890.99",
  "ASUS|UNKNOWN|P5KC|P35|1|50.00"
];
```

Comment: I checked and **groups** array is tring type, also it's elements are strings. I pasted this array unquoted, cause i pasted it from console, where there was a result of creating this array from other array with some **split** method